# How can I see files that are staged in git in IntelliJ / WebStorm?

Tags: intellij-idea, webstorm, rider

In the Version Control tool window of IntelliJ / WebStorm / Rider, files that are unversioned, new or changed have different colors.

I am wondering if there is a way to visually see the ones that have been staged in git?